# Aspnetboilerplate - No Social Login documentation available

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

It seems there's no documentation regarding Social Login.

I went here:
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management#social-logins

And the Social Login topic is supposed to be discussed here:
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template

Does this means Social Login implementation has been removed from the Boilerplate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup Social Login in ASP.NET Boilerplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808179/how-to-setup-social-login-in-asp-net-boilerplate)

Answer (score 0):

It was not done for ABP v3.0.0 as there are tutorials for ASP.NET Core 2.x:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/

If you are using an earlier version like ABP v2.3.0, refer to the [documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/v2.3.0/Zero/Startup-Template#social-logins) reproduced here:

> Startup template supports **Facebook**, **Twitter** and **Google+** logins. In the web.config, you can see the following settings:
>
> ```
> <add key="ExternalAuth.Facebook.IsEnabled" value="false" />
> <add key="ExternalAuth.Facebook.AppId" value="" />
> <add key="ExternalAuth.Facebook.AppSecret" value="" />
>
> <add key="ExternalAuth.Twitter.IsEnabled" value="false" />
> <add key="ExternalAuth.Twitter.ConsumerKey" value="" />
> <add key="ExternalAuth.Twitter.ConsumerSecret" value="" />
>
> <add key="ExternalAuth.Google.IsEnabled" value="false" />
> <add key="ExternalAuth.Google.ClientId" value="" />
> <add key="ExternalAuth.Google.ClientSecret" value="" />
> ```
>
> Here, you can enable which you need. Surely, you must have application keys and passwords which you need to get from related social web site. You can find guides from web to learn how to obtain this keys. Once you enable a social login and enter true keys, you will see a button in the login page. You can implement other logins as similar.

ABP owner's comment: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2406#issuecomment-323978304