# How to setup Social Login in ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, configuration, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to authenticate users through Google.
I'm using the ABP startup template for ASP.NET Core with Vue.

Here's what I have done so far:

I've created a `GoogleAuthProviderApi` in Web.Core:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Mindbus.MindbooksSEO.Authentication.External.Google
{
    public class GoogleAuthProviderApi : ExternalAuthProviderApiBase
    {
        public const string Name = "Google";

        public override async Task<ExternalAuthUserInfo> GetUserInfo(string accessCode)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Microsoft ASP.NET Core OAuth middleware");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd("application/json");
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10; // 10 MB

                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, GoogleDefaults.UserInformationEndpoint);
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessCode);

                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var payload = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                return new ExternalAuthUserInfo
                {
                    //Name = GoogleHelper.GetName(payload),
                    EmailAddress = GoogleHelper.GetEmail(payload),
                    //Surname = GoogleHelper.GetFamilyName(payload),
                    //ProviderKey = GoogleHelper.GetId(payload),
                    Provider = Name
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've registered the Google External Authentication in **AuthConfigurer.cs** in Web.Host:

```cs
if (bool.Parse(configuration["Authentication:Google:IsEnabled"]))
{
    services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        googleOptions.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    });
}
```

I've added the settings to **appsettings.json** in Web.Host, and created the corresponding secrets (**ClientId** and **ClientSecret**) in the Secret Manager tool.

I've forced the API to SSL with the `RequireHttpsAttribute`.

I've registered the `GoogleAuthProviderApi` in the **[ProjectName]WebCoreModule.cs**:

```cs
public override void PreInitialize()
{
    Configuration.DefaultNameOrConnectionString = _appConfiguration.GetConnectionString(
        MindbooksSEOConsts.ConnectionStringName
    );

    // Use database for language management
    Configuration.Modules.Zero().LanguageManagement.EnableDbLocalization();

    Configuration.Modules.AbpAspNetCore()
            .CreateControllersForAppServices(
                typeof(MindbooksSEOApplicationModule).GetAssembly()
            );

    ConfigureTokenAuth();

    Configuration.Modules.Zero().UserManagement.ExternalAuthenticationSources.Add<GoogleAuthProviderApi>();
}
```

I don't know what I'm missing here, nor do I know what to expect exactly.

I would have thought that a call to the **api/TokenAuth/GetExternalAuthenticationProviders** endpoint would at least give me a list with Google in it, but this request returns with an empty array in the results.

Additionally, it's a bit unclear to me what the scope of this external authentication is, in the case of OAuth providers such as Google and Facebook. It seems to me that you either have OAuth for server-side usage, in which case I don't understand why you would expose part of it through the API. Or you have OAuth for JavaScript web apps, in which case you don't need an API endpoint on your own server, you just handle the entire thing client-side through the web app.

So, what's the purpose exactly of the External Authenticate API endpoint? Is it so that your own server acts as a proxy for authentication? So that you can have both client-side and server-side usage of the External (Google) API?

### Update 1

The comments require me to add some clarification.

**#1**: If I add the `Abp.TenantId` header in Postman, the response remains the same:

```
GET /api/TokenAuth/GetExternalAuthenticationProviders HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44300
Accept: application/json
Abp.TenantId: 2
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 0cb72e57-4b9a-474d-b60d-492fa727a7a2
```

**#2**: The console "tricks" in Swagger result in errors:

```js
abp.swagger.login()
undefined
VM40:49 POST https://localhost:44300/api/TokenAuth/Authenticate 500 ()
abp.swagger.login @ VM40:49
(anonymous) @ VM84:1
abp.swagger.addAuthToken()
false
```

### Update 2

I think there's something wrong with the `GoogleAuthProviderApi`. After I made the debugger break on all CLR Exceptions, I caught the following error:

```
'Mindbus.MindbooksSEO.Authentication.External.Google.GoogleAuthProviderApi' to type
 'Abp.Authorization.Users.IExternalAuthenticationSource`2
[Mindbus.MindbooksSEO.MultiTenancy.Tenant,
Mindbus.MindbooksSEO.Authorization.Users.User]'.'
```

Comment: Did you send `Abp.TenantId` header when calling `GetExternalAuthenticationProviders`?

Comment: No, I didn't because in the Swagger UI I don't see how you can. Let me fiddle along with Postman and see what it'll get me and I'll get back to you.

Comment: For your last question, yes you can use your own server as an authentication authority  like Facebook login. And you can make Gijswijs Login for other websites.

Comment: GetExternalAuthenticationProviders only returns value when there's a tenant (on host side it is not supported) so send the Abp.TenantId

Comment: "GetExternalAuthenticationProviders only returns value when there's a tenant (on host side it is not supported) so send the Abp.TenantId" Why wouldn't it work without a login...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## ASP.NET Core 1.x or MVC 5

1. Note that the configuration for [Social Login](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/v2.3.0/Zero/Startup-Template#social-logins) **providers** (e.g. Google) is quite different from [External Authentication](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management#external-authentication) **sources** (e.g. LDAP). So, remove this line:

   <s>`Configuration.Modules.Zero().UserManagement.ExternalAuthenticationSources.Add<GoogleAuthProviderApi>();`</s>
2. Observe that `GetExternalAuthenticationProviders` looks in `IExternalAuthConfiguration`.
   So, configure `IExternalAuthConfiguration` in `PostInitialize` method of `*WebHostModule`:

   ```cs
   if (bool.Parse(configuration["Authentication:Google:IsEnabled"]))
   {
       var externalAuthConfiguration = IocManager.Resolve<IExternalAuthConfiguration>();

       externalAuthConfiguration.Providers.Add(
           new ExternalLoginProviderInfo(
               GoogleAuthProviderApi.Name,
               configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"],
               configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"],
               typeof(GoogleAuthProviderApi)
           )
       );
   }
   ```

## ASP.NET Core 2.x

Although the above way of handling Social Login providers may work, it is [no longer recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46923402/8601760).

The built-in `.AddGoogle` way:

```cs
if (bool.Parse(configuration["Authentication:Google:IsEnabled"]))
{
    services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        googleOptions.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    });
}
```

...is meant to be used with:

```cs
var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(
    info.LoginProvider,
    info.ProviderKey,
    isPersistent: false,
    bypassTwoFactor : true
);
```

And the way to get external authentication **schemes** is:

```cs
var schemes = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
```

You can modify `GetExternalAuthenticationProviders` to return this data.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive reply. I think I understand it. An additional question is: The external authentication schemes do not map onto ExternalLoginProviderInfoModel. Do you propose to alter the ExternalLoginProviderInfoModel?

Comment: Yes, I suppose.

Comment: Hmm we need better docs about this. We can either read the Microsoft tutorial and do it entirely out of ABP, or use this, but it's not the whole story. So we need something more official I think.

Comment: @aaron but I thought ExternalLogin was nothing to do with Social logins?

Comment: No, **sources** has (almost) nothing to do with **providers/schemes**. "ExternalLoginProviders** refers to the **providers**; it's naming is unfortunate.

Comment: @aaron any sign of some documentation? There seems to be a lot of confusion out there regarding this.

Comment: I came across that and while it helps, there's a still a lot figuring out to do. Documentation would really, really help.

Comment: You can comment on that issue.

Comment: @aaron done! Is this something that will be acted on or does it need more attention from the community?

Comment: It is low priority, as it's not broken and the information already exists in some form. The benefits do not justify the effort. Community contribution is always welcome.

Answer (score 2):

For those guys who visit this topic and don't find an answer (as me).

aspnetcore 2.2 and abp 4.5.0 Facebook working example

*WebHostModule.cs

```
public override void PostInitialize()
        {
            var externalAuthConfiguration = IocManager.Resolve<IExternalAuthConfiguration>();
            externalAuthConfiguration.Providers.Add(
                 new ExternalLoginProviderInfo(
                    FacebookAuthProvider.Name,
                    configuration["Authentication:Facebook:ClientId"],
                    configuration["Authentication:Facebook:Secret"],
                    typeof(FacebookAuthProvider)
                )
            );           
        }
```

*FacebookAuthProvider.cs

```
public class FacebookAuthProvider: ExternalAuthProviderApiBase
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
        public const string Name = "Facebook";
        public override async Task<ExternalAuthUserInfo> GetUserInfo(string accessCode)
        {
            //gen app access token
            var appAccessTokenResponse = await Client.GetStringAsync("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token" +
              "?client_id=" + ProviderInfo.ClientId +
              "&client_secret=" + ProviderInfo.ClientSecret +
              "&grant_type=client_credentials");
            var appAccessToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookAppAccessToken>(appAccessTokenResponse);
            //validate user access token
            var userAccessTokenValidationResponse = await Client.GetStringAsync("https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/debug_token" +
                "?input_token="+ accessCode +
                "&access_token="+ appAccessToken.AccessToken);
            var userAccessTokenValidation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookUserAccessTokenValidation>(userAccessTokenValidationResponse);
            if (!userAccessTokenValidation.Data.IsValid)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("login_failure Invalid facebook token.");
            }

            //get userinfo
            var userInfoResponse = await Client.GetStringAsync($"https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me?fields=id,email,first_name,last_name&access_token={accessCode}");
            var userInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookUserData>(userInfoResponse);

            return new ExternalAuthUserInfo
            {
                Name = userInfo.FirstName,
                EmailAddress = userInfo.Email,
                Surname=userInfo.LastName,
                Provider=Name,
                ProviderKey=userInfo.Id.ToString()
            };

        }
    }
```

Models

```
internal class FacebookUserData
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("first_name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("last_name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Locale { get; set; }
        public FacebookPictureData Picture { get; set; }
    }

    internal class FacebookPictureData
    {
        public FacebookPicture Data { get; set; }
    }

    internal class FacebookPicture
    {
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("is_silhouette")]
        public bool IsSilhouette { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }

    internal class FacebookUserAccessTokenData
    {
        [JsonProperty("app_id")]
        public long AppId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Application { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("expires_at")]
        public long ExpiresAt { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("is_valid")]
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("user_id")]
        public long UserId { get; set; }
    }

    internal class FacebookUserAccessTokenValidation
    {
        public FacebookUserAccessTokenData Data { get; set; }
    }

    internal class FacebookAppAccessToken
    {
        [JsonProperty("token_type")]
        public string TokenType { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("access_token")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you explain how did you manage the Facebook redirection? Did you redirect to the /api/TokenAuth/ExternalAuthenticate?

Comment: I used the Facebook "button plugin"  to get access code on frontend and example above to prove code and get user info. I just send this data from js without redirection.

Comment: As you can see, ExternalAuthenticate method accepts provider name, userid and access code. So you cannot simply redirect Facebook to this method.